# polymorphism without virtual methods

Tags: java

According to book SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide, "all java objects are polimorphic".

`class B {}
class A extends B {}`

Class A doesn't have any overriden methods. Is it polymorphic ?

Comment: if "all java objects are polymorphic" then by definition it would be.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely, because class B extends Object and Object has a few methods already.

Answer (score 2):

By default every object inherits from Object so overall the answer is yes